# Embedded Stylesheet in external assembly for asp.net Core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, embedded-resource

I am using **VS.2017 Community Edition** with **15.2 update** (26430.12) and in my solution I have a main **ASP.NET Core 1.1** web application and a *separate assembly which is a .NET Core class library* which I have rigged so that it is the Web SDK as class library and from where I provide view components to the main web application. That works fine.

However, I have just added a couple of partial views (perhaps view components later on) but these two in particular do need a stylesheet (CSS) file to be included. Since I want everything self contained like the visual components, I created a wwwroot\css folder and therein I put my CSS and made it an embedded resource.

The question is.... in my main web application how do I go about streaming that stylesheet in the ASP.NET Core _Layout file given the stylesheet is embedded in the external assembly?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files)
, I think theoretically you could add an embedded file provider to static files middleware like this:

```
var embeddedFiles = new EmbeddedFileProvider(
                typeof(yourtype).GetTypeInfo().Assembly,
                "your.assembly.name"
            );

builder.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = embeddedFiles
    //,RequestPath = new PathString("/files") // optionally use a path other than /
});
```

If that way works it is probably best, but I have not tried it myself so not 100% sure that works. Currently in my project I have just added controller actions that returns my embedded static resources which you can see in the css, js, and fonts actionmethods in my [FileManagerController](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.SimpleContent/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.FileManager.Web/Controllers/FileManagerController.cs)

My FileManagerController needs css and js and fonts so I have action methods for each of those and a private helper action method. It works, but when I get a chance I would try the other way as it would be much less code.
The urls for my resources are like [controller]/action so filemanager/css, filemanager/js, filemanager/fonts in my case.

UPDATE 2017-06-09: I have now implemented serving embedded static resources in my own project using the StaticFiles Middleware approach. I can confirm it works in general but there is an issue if the embedded resource has any - in folder segments the resource was not found because - in folder segments needs to be changed to _ to find the resource but - in file names is ok. The EmbeddedFileProvider does not handle this so I reported an issue [here](https://github.com/aspnet/FileSystem/issues/277) and solved it with a [custom IFileProvider](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.Web.Common/Components/EmbeddedFileResolvingProvider.cs) in my project.

It is also possible as mentioned to serve static resources from controller actions, but MVC runs after authentication/authorization middleware so the result is that those middlewares run in processing the static file requests which can be avoided using static files middleware that runs before that. I guess if there was a need to protect embedded static resources then using controller actions would be a way to do that, but I don't need it in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Well, so far for me this .NET Core thing is complicating my life rather than making it easier. Anyway, I managed to get the CSS file residing in the same external assembly where the (external) view components are embedded served in my _Layout.

For one thing, I added a new API method to the **SampleAPI** *API controller* of the main web application. This API method retrieves the embedded resource in the external assembly and gets its stream.

Let us say the full namespace of the external assembly where the view component requiring a custom CSS is embedded has a **namespace** **ExternalAssembly** and there I defined my component and its CSS file. I am omitting the full view component for clarity.

```
ExternalAssembly.proj
     css\
        my-view-component.css
     ViewComponents\
        MyViewComponent.cs
     Views\
        Shared\
           Components\
              MyViewComponent\
                  Default.cshtml
```

The Default.cshtml file and the CSS files are marked in the project as *embedded resources*.

The API method on the API controller looks like this, my application is an **ASP.NET Core 1.1 MVC** but has an API as well. The API method takes care of returning the CSS file as a stream for use in your layout page:

```
[HttpGet("cssMyViewComponent")]
public IActionResult GetCss(string id) {
    var stream = typeof(ExternalAssembly.ViewComponents.MyViewComponent)
 .GetTypeInfo().Assembly
 .GetManifestResourceStream("ExternalAssembly.css.my-view-component.css");
}
```

Make sure to get the actual name of the embedded resource, notice the css folder name is part of the full namespace of that resource. If unsure you can open up the external assembly with ILDASM and look up the name of the resource.

Last but not least I reference the CSS in the **_Layout.cshtml** like this using the name of the API method and the route defined for it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/api/SampleAPI/cssMyViewComponent" />
```